# Snakemake, trouble with "lambda wildcards, attempt, threads"

Tags: python, snakemake

I was using snakemake to implement a new tool in a pipeline and i had some trouble with those lines:

```
resources:
    # Samtools sort requires by default 768M per threads
    # Here, be set the maximum amount of memory are 1.5Go per threads
    mem_mb = (
        lambda wildcards, attempt, threads: min(
        attempt * 250 + threads * 768,
        1536 * threads)
    )
```

the error is :

```
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'threads'
Wildcards:
sample=test_GATK
genome=fakefile
```

To make those lines i used the documentation on this page : 
[snakemake documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#resources)

To fix this issue i use this code instead:

```
resources:
    # Samtools sort requires by default 768M per threads
    # Here, be set the maximum amount of memory are 1.5Go per threads
    mem_mb = (
        lambda wildcards, attempt: min(
        attempt * 250 + config["threads"] * 768,
        1536 * config["threads"])
    )
```

I don't know why the previous one is not working, can you help me figure it out ?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't post an answer inside of your question. Rather add a real answer to it. This has the effect that other users can 1. see that there is an answer to this problem (if they have the same one) and 2. see that your problem is already solved and doesn't require their help anymore.

Comment: @derHugo: there is no answer yet, just OP attempt ofa solution

Answer (score 0):

My reading of the docs is that callable requires 4 parameters and you supply 3 out of order.

Maybe make a lambda with 4 args? If it where mot an init file, I would also say - make a function instead of a lambda and then 3 keyword args can fit.

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer, i already tried with all four arguments in all possible orders and i have the same error.

Comment: Just a wild guess - are you positive this is exactly where the error is? Maybe there is a similar call elsewhere?

Comment: I am looking for another potential error but i did not find another one for now. I'll tell if i do.

Comment: Sorry, it did not help

Comment: you helped, i eliminated some posibilities thanks to you.